# Laravel select smallest value

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a site where orders are assigned to employees.
I'm assigning the new orders to the employees with the lowest amount of orders assigned to.

My current code to find that employee:

```
$employees=User::whereHas('employee', function ($q) use ($company) {
        $q->where('company_id', $company->id);
    })->get();
    $min='999';
    foreach ($employees as $employee)
    {
        if(Order::where('assigned_to_employee',$employee->id)->count()<$min)
        {
            $assign_id=$employee->id;
            $min=Order::where('assigned_to_employee',$employee->id)->count();
        }
    }
```

I feel like there is a better way to do this so recommendations are welcome.
Also if my way of doing it is good how do I assign to $min a max int value?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand, but I think you'd benefit from the following if you are using Laravel 5.3.  You should be able to use a combination of withCount and orderBy to get a list of employees with the lowest amount of orders.

```
User::withCount('employee')->orderBy('employee_count', 'asc')->first();
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that order assigned to employee is stored in the orders table not in employee table.